# how to make Cmake output relative path？

Tags: cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my last deleted question about CMake, I raised a problem about how to make CMake output relative path because  vscode's problem panel only
understanding Windows directories or relative paths under workspace.

This won't happen unless some specific situation. If you use vsocde to edit source files in Windows and use WSL as terminal to compile using CMake, you will find vscode cannot work perfectly.

1. the  problem panel will tell you it could not find the error or warning's source code after compilation completes.
2. gdb could not find source file when debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)Solution to the first problem:Add the following code to your outermost CMakeLists.txt:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/custom_output.sh")
```

The global RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE property is set to a custom launch script named custom_output.sh which needs to be added to the root of the CMake source tree:

```
  #!/bin/bash
    
    # shell script invoked with the following arguments
    # $(CXX) $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o OBJECT_FILE -c SOURCE_FILE
    
    # extract parameters
    SOURCE_FILE="${@: -1:1}"
    OBJECT_FILE="${@: -3:1}"
    
    # invoke compiler 
    { "$@" 2> >(sed 's@^/mnt/d/demo/@@'|sed "s/warning/${esc}[32m&${esc}[0m/g"|sed "s/error/${esc}[31m&${esc}[0m/g" >&3); } 3>&2
```

it would output stderr messages also on stderr and transform it to relative path.Where "/mnt/d/demo/" is the string to be deleted. What to delete depends on the source code relative path.

(2)You can use the following command from gdb for remapping to solve the second problem:

```
set substitute-path old_path new_path
```

You need add follow code to you launch.json

```
 "customLaunchSetupCommands": [
                            {
                                "text": "set substitute-path /mnt/d d:/",
                                "description": "change directory to workspace",
                                "ignoreFailures": false
                            }
        ]
```

If you debug with Cortex Debug you should add follw code to you launch.json

```
"postLaunchCommands": ["set substitute-path /mnt/d d:/"]
```

Comment: Using logfile will be not reentrant. Just `"$@" | while read ...`. But just `"$@" | sed 's@^/mnt/d/demo@@'` or `"$@" 2> >(sed 's@^/mnt/d/demo@@')`

Comment: Och, second thought, the `2> >(sed 's@^/mnt/d/demo@@')` will redirect stderr to stdout. So something like `{ "$@" 2> >(sed 's@^/mnt/d/demo@@' >&3); } 3>&2` would be better - it would output stderr messages also on stderr.

Comment: Allow me to express my most sincere gratitude to you.